# CSS white transparent div

Tags: css, background

I making a white transparent div to highlight my content. I know is using `background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);` but I also have background image. How can I with background image also have the white transparent color?

```
.div {
    width: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    height: 80px;
    background: url('../img/dark_embroidery.png');
    background-repeat: repeat;  
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
```

Comment: You will have to make the image transparent.

Comment: You can use the opacity property as well: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_transparency.asp

Comment: you want like this effect. http://jsbin.com/rabubocozo/1/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Background color in under background image. If image isn't transparent and has full size of div, white background is hidden.

You can use second element for set white overlay.

```
<style>
    .div {/* your styles */}
    .div > div {background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5)}
</style>    

<div class=div>
    <div>
        CONTENT
    </div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle.net/9gadzskv](http://jsfiddle.net/9gadzskv)

Or, the second way, make you png image transparent (or better said, add opacity to png image).

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to edit your image or use additional markup, you can achieve this using an absolutely positioned pseudo element.

Give your `div` the following styles:

```
.div{
    background:url(../img/dark_embroidery.png) no-repeat;
    height:80px;
    padding:20px;
    position:relative;
    width:auto;
}
.div:before{
    background:rgba(255,255,255,.5);
    bottom:0;
    content:"";
    display:block;
    left:0;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top:0;
}
```

Another option would be to use multiple backgrounds. You do so by providing a comma separated list of backgrounds you wish to use, which will be layered, top to bottom, in the order they are provided. Note, though, that only images can be used here so you will need to use a gradient for the white.

```
.div{
    background:linear-gradient(0deg,rgba(255,255,255,.5),rgba(255,255,255,.5)),url(../img/dark_embroidery.png) no-repeat;
    height:80px;
    padding:20px;
    position:relative;
    width:auto;
}
```

- [More information on pseudo elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements)
- [More information on multiple backgrounds](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_multiple_backgrounds)